# JQuery loop through array somehow passing by reference

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop, pass-by-reference

So I have a very simple function that is not working. It's supposed to loop through an array of navigation names, and link each navigation button with a call to another function using the navigation name as a parameter. For some reason it is linking every button to call the function with the last navigation name as a parameter. So whether you click 'Gigs', 'Music', 'Videos', etc it calls getPage('Contact'). I'm thinking that it's somehow passing by reference but I can't figure out how or why.

I instantiate the array at the top:

`var navLinks = new Array('Blog', 'Gigs', 'Music', 'Videos', 'Photos', 'Band', 'Contact');`

And then run through it like this:

```
var foo;

// Add nav links
for(var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {

    $('#' + navLinks[i] + 'Nav');

    foo = "'" + navLinks[i] + "'";

    if( (page != 'Videos' && page != 'Photos') && (curPage != 'Videos' && curPage != 'Photos') )

        $('#' + navLinks[i] + 'Nav').click(function() { getPage( foo, 0) } );

    else

        $('#' + navLinks[i] + 'Nav').click(function() { getPage( foo, 1) } ); 

    $('#' + navLinks[i] + 'Nav').css('cursor', 'pointer');

} // End add nav links
```

I threw the foo in while experimenting. The really confusing part is that it does link every element, so it's going through all the options; and when I throw an alert to check foo in each iteration it alerts for all the individual options. I am very frustrated at the moment, thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like you have problem with [JavaScript closures.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the callback function `function() { getPage( foo, 1) }`, you're *closing over* the `foo` variable, and `foo` changes as you run your `for` loop, so by the time the callback is invoked, the value of `foo` is the last value it had at the end of the loop.

You need to create a new variable context, by calling into a function. For example:

```
var foo;

function addHandler(i, foo, x){
   $('#' + navLinks[i] + 'Nav').click(function() { getPage( foo, x) });
}
// Add nav links
for(var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    $('#' + navLinks[i] + 'Nav');
    foo = "'" + navLinks[i] + "'";
    var x = (page != 'Videos' && page != 'Photos') && (curPage != 'Videos' && curPage != 'Photos') 
        ? 0 
        : 1
    addHandler(i, foo, x);

    $('#' + navLinks[i] + 'Nav').css('cursor', 'pointer');

} // End add nav links
```

Because calling into addHandler captures the *values* of its parameters rather than capturing the variables themselves, `addHandler` is capturing a different variable each time it gets called.